# R Edit data frame in function within function

Tags: r, function

I have a code made up of a lot of functions used for different codes and which will modify a df by adding some columns. I need to have a global function that takes over several of these functions, but since they are functions inside another function, my df does not update this on every function call. Do you have any advice for this problem?

Here is an example of my problem :

```
f_a<-function(df){
  df$x<-1
  .GlobalEnv$df <- df
}
  
f_b<-function(df){
  df$y<-1
  .GlobalEnv$df <- df
}

f_global<-function(df){
  f_a(df)
  f_b(df)
}
```

In this case df will not have the x and y columns created

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea for functions to have "side effects":  things are easier to get right if functions are completely self contained.  For your example, that would look like this:

```
f_a<-function(df){
  df$x<-1    # This only changes the local copy
  df         # This returns the local copy as the function result 
}

f_b<-function(df){
  df$y<-1
  df
}

f_global<-function(df){
  df <- f_a(df)    # This uses f_a to change the local copy
  df <- f_b(df)    # This uses f_b to make another change
  df               # This returns the changed dataframe
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(z = 1)
mydf <- f_global(mydf)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this operator <<- in the function.as an example:

```
dat = data.frame(x1 = rep(1,10),x2 = rep(2,10),x3 = rep(3,10))
head(dat)
myFun <- function(x){
  print(x)
  dat$x1 <<- rep(5,10)
}
myFun(10)  
head(dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the call to `f_b` the input argument `df` is assigned to `.GlobalEnv` rewriting the `df` that already existed there. So `f_global` first calls `f_a` and creates a column `x`, then calls `f_b` passing it its input data.frame and `f_b`  creates a column `y` *in this df*.
All that needs to be changed is `f_global`:

```
f_global<-function(df){
  f_a(df)
  f_b(.GlobalEnv$df)
}

f_global(data.frame(a=1))
df
#  a x y
#1 1 1 1

df <- head(mtcars)
f_global(df)
df
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb x y
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 1 1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 1 1
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1 1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 1 1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 1 1
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 1 1
```

---

Though the code above works and follows the lines of the question, I think that a better strategy is to have `f_global` change its input argument assigning the return value of each `f_*` and assign the end result in `f_global`'s parent environment only after all transformations are done.

```
f_a <- function(df){
  df$x <- 1
  df
}

f_b <- function(df){
  df$y <- 1
  df
}

f_global <- function(df){
  dfname <- deparse(substitute(df))
  df <- f_a(df)
  df <- f_b(df)
  assign(dfname, df, envir = parent.frame())
  invisible(NULL)
}

df1 <- data.frame(a=1)
f_global(df1)
df1

df <- head(mtcars)
f_global(df)
df
```

Comment: Nonstandard evaluation is necessary sometimes (e.g. labels on a plot), but you shouldn't use it when you don't have to.   It imposes strange restrictions on the user:  for example, your `f_global` will do strange things if called from a function, or if called with a function call as argument.  Keeping code simple and easy to understand is important.

Comment: @user2554330 I agree with that. That's why I have upvoted your answer, it should be the accepted one. My answer is based 1) on the OP's code; 2) on the assumption that it will not be called  from another function.